# How to download Scribd files with wget?

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I would like to download some pdf files in scribd, but i am a beginner in command line tools like wget. What command to use? Or You can suggest me also other terminal Tools

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading `man wget`. Some options I use with `wget` are: `--no-parent --relative --page-requisites --convert-links -nv -t 3 --waitretry=6 --random-wait`, but that is all explained in the `man` page.